# React-Dates in component using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-dates

As a newbie in React and Redux, i'm trying to use [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) in a component.

This is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as DateState from '../store/Date';
import * as SingleDatePicker from 'react-dates';

type DateProps = DateState.DateState & typeof DateState.actionCreators;

class DatePickerSingle extends React.Component<DateProps, any> {

    public render() {

        let { date } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <SingleDatePicker
                    id="date_input"
                    date={this.props.date}
                    focused={this.state.focused}
                    onDateChange={(date) => { this.props.user({ date }); }}
                    onFocusChange={({ focused }) => { this.setState({ focused }); }}
                    isOutsideRange={() => false}
                    displayFormat="dddd LL">
                </SingleDatePicker>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.date, 
    DateState.actionCreators                 
)(DatePickerSingle);
```

This returns the following error:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'focused' of null
```

`focused` an `onFocusChange` should receive the "datepicker state" as far as I understand.

Docs:

> onFocusChange is the callback necessary to update the focus state in
>   the parent component. It expects a single argument of the form {
>   focused: PropTypes.bool }.

I think the problem is that I inject the `DateState` in the `DatePickerSingle` component, which doesn't know about `focused` state.

Is it possible to use my "own" state and the state from the DatePicker together? Or what is the best approach?

I'm trying for quite a while now, and I hope someone can help me with this.

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: `this.state` is null because it has not been initialized. Just add

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    focused: false
  }
}
```

Anything coming from redux will be passed to your component as `props`, you can have component state in addition to that.

Comment: Thank you @OlliM! Though I'm getting the following error now: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null`.. When I'm moving the cursor on `this.setState({ focused })` in Visual Studio, there is still no `focused` see screenshot in my updated question.

Comment: Hmm that error seems to be solved, but still I get this error: `Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of 'DatePickerSingle'.`

Comment: Found the problem. The date attribute in the `singledatepicker` component was expecting a Momentjs [link](https://momentjs.com/) object. In my reducer I already formatted it, so it became a string. Everything works as expected now. Thank you for your help!